# Problems with value inserting into database

Tags: javascript, php, html

So I have this function that creates textareas deepending on the month. So if it is March, then 31 textareas, April, then 30 textareas and so on. When the user clicks on one textarea and then the submit button, the value of the textarea should be submitted to the db. So if the user marks 2018-02-04, then that date should be inserted into the db. But, my problem right now is that the only value that is submitted is the last date of each month. Not sure why, and dont know how to solve it. Think it might be something with IDs.

Functions:

```
var showDate = new Date();
var months = ["Januari", "Februari", "March", "April", "May", "June",
              "July", "Augusti", "September", "October", "November", "December"];
var weeks = ["Sunday","Monday","Tuseday","Wednesday","Thursday","Friday","Saturday"];


function drawTable(forDate) {
    var daysInMonth = new Date(forDate.getFullYear(),forDate.getMonth()+1,0).getDate();
    var cellsToDraw = daysInMonth;
    var newdate = forDate.getFullYear() +"-"+ ("0"+ (forDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    var table = document.getElementById("table");
    table.innerHTML = "";
    for (var r = 0; r < (daysInMonth / 7); r++) {
        var newRow = document.createElement("tr");
        table.appendChild(newRow);
        for (var c = 0; c < 31 && cellsToDraw > 0; c++) {
            var day1 = ("0" + (c + 1)).slice(-2);

            var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
            textarea.setAttribute("placeholder", day1 );
            //textarea.setAttribute("id", some_value); does not work
            newRow.appendChild(textarea);
            textarea.setAttribute("name", "day");
            textarea.setAttribute("day",  newdate + "-" + day1 )
            textarea.innerHTML = newdate + "-" + day1;
            cellsToDraw--;
        }
    }
}

window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("displayingMonth").innerHTML = months[showDate.getMonth()];
    drawTable(showDate );
};

function next() {
    if (showDate.getMonth() == 11) {
        showDate.setMonth( 0 );
        showDate.setFullYear( showDate.getFullYear()+1 );
    } else {
        showDate.setMonth( showDate.getMonth()+1 );
    }
    document.getElementById("displayingMonth").innerHTML = months[showDate.getMonth()];
    drawTable( showDate );
}
```

html:

```
<form class="" action="index.php" method="post">
      <table id="table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"   border-collapse="collapse";>
         <br>
         <input id="btn"  type="submit" name="" value="Send">
       </form>
```

php:

```
<?php
include ("connection.php");
$day = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_REQUEST['day']);

$stmt = "INSERT INTO table (day) VALUES('$day')";
if(empty($day)){
  $_SESSION['error'] = "Please fill in required fields";

  header('Location: index.php', true, 303);
  exit();
} else {
  if (mysqli_query($conn, $stmt)) {
    header('Location: index.php', true, 303);
        exit;
  }else {
    $error= "Error: " .mysqli_error($conn);
    echo "$error";

  }
}

?>
```

All help is appriciated! :)

Comment: You need to tell the browser that you're sending an array but adding `[]` to the end of the element's name parameter. But then your php will also need to be modified to allow for arrays.

Comment: Giving a `<textarea>` tag a "type" attribute doesn't make sense; the type is always "textarea".

Comment: @JonStirling I have looked in to that, but not sure how it works. Last time I tried it everything crashed...

Comment: @Pointy thanks for the heads up! It shouldent have been there. Removed it!

Comment: Unrelated to the topic, but since you're using `mysqli` you should look into using [prepared statments](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) as it's more secure than `mysqli_real_escape_string`

Comment: That makes it an X-Y problem. Perhaps it would be better to try again and be asking why that isn't working.

Comment: Hi @Hanna if this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.

Comment: @LucaGiardina hi! I know about that, but unfortunately I did not find the answer that helped me..

Comment: @Hanna you answer was: "But, my problem right now is that the only value that is submitted is the last date of each month. Not sure why, and dont know how to solve it. Think it might be something with IDs." It's solved. Now you probably have another one :)

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OQBxga

Comment: @LucaGiardina did you add any php to the code? or no?

Comment: @Hanna, of course you should use php to handle the form submition. The php code should be the same that you posted.

Answer (score 0):

First i suggest you to check always your output.. that's what your javascript create.

```
<form class="" action="index.php" method="post">
    <br><input id="btn" type="submit" name="" value="Send">
    <table id="table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border-collapse="collapse" ;="">
        <tr>
            <textarea placeholder="01" name="day" day="2018-02-01">2018-02-01</textarea>
            <textarea placeholder="02" name="day" day="2018-02-02">2018-02-02</textarea>
            <textarea placeholder="03" name="day" day="2018-02-03">2018-02-03</textarea>
            <textarea placeholder="04" name="day" day="2018-02-04">2018-02-04</textarea>
            <textarea placeholder="05" name="day" day="2018-02-05">2018-02-05</textarea>
            <textarea placeholder="06" name="day" day="2018-02-06">2018-02-06</textarea>
            <textarea placeholder="07" name="day" day="2018-02-07">2018-02-07</textarea>
            <textarea placeholder="08" name="day" day="2018-02-08">2018-02-08</textarea>
            <textarea placeholder="09" name="day" day="2018-02-09">2018-02-09</textarea>
            <textarea placeholder="10" name="day" day="2018-02-10">2018-02-10</textarea>
            <textarea placeholder="11" name="day" day="2018-02-11">2018-02-11</textarea>
            <textarea placeholder="12" name="day" day="2018-02-12">2018-02-12</textarea>
            <textarea placeholder="13" name="day" day="2018-02-13">2018-02-13</textarea>
            <textarea placeholder="14" name="day" day="2018-02-14">2018-02-14</textarea>

            <textarea placeholder="15" name="day" day="2018-02-15">2018-02-15</textarea>
            <textarea placeholder="16" name="day" day="2018-02-16">2018-02-16</textarea>
            <textarea placeholder="17" name="day" day="2018-02-17">2018-02-17</textarea>
            <textarea placeholder="18" name="day" day="2018-02-18">2018-02-18</textarea>

            <textarea placeholder="19" name="day" day="2018-02-19">2018-02-19</textarea>
            <textarea placeholder="20" name="day" day="2018-02-20">2018-02-20</textarea>
            <textarea placeholder="21" name="day" day="2018-02-21">2018-02-21</textarea>
            <textarea placeholder="22" name="day" day="2018-02-22">2018-02-22</textarea>

            <textarea placeholder="23" name="day" day="2018-02-23">2018-02-23</textarea>
            <textarea placeholder="24" name="day" day="2018-02-24">2018-02-24</textarea>
            <textarea placeholder="25" name="day" day="2018-02-25">2018-02-25</textarea>
            <textarea placeholder="26" name="day" day="2018-02-26">2018-02-26</textarea>

            <textarea placeholder="27" name="day" day="2018-02-27">2018-02-27</textarea>
            <textarea placeholder="28" name="day" day="2018-02-28">2018-02-28</textarea>
        </tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
        <tr></tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

As you can see you will always get last textarea's "day" value because your form doesn't have a unique value for the "day" attribute

You should add a form, with a submit button, for each textarea or totally rework your code..

quick solution:

html

```
<form class="" action="index.php" method="post">
    <input id="day" type="hidden" name="day" value="">
    <table id="table" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"   border-collapse="collapse";>
    <br>
    <input id="btn"  type="submit" name="" value="Send">
</form>
```

js, remove the "name" from textarea. Add in drawTable the event listener "onchange"

```
function drawTable(forDate) {
    var daysInMonth = new Date(forDate.getFullYear(),forDate.getMonth()+1,0).getDate();
    var cellsToDraw = daysInMonth;
    var newdate = forDate.getFullYear() +"-"+ ("0"+ (forDate.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    var table = document.getElementById("table");
    table.innerHTML = "";
    for (var r = 0; r < (daysInMonth / 7); r++) {
        var newRow = document.createElement("tr");
        table.appendChild(newRow);
        for (var c = 0; c < 31 && cellsToDraw > 0; c++) {
            var day1 = ("0" + (c + 1)).slice(-2);

            var textarea = document.createElement("textarea");
            textarea.setAttribute("placeholder", day1 );
            //textarea.setAttribute("id", some_value); does not work
            newRow.appendChild(textarea);
            textarea.setAttribute("onchange", "document.getElementById('day').value = '" + newdate + "-" + day1 + "'");
            textarea.innerHTML = newdate + "-" + day1;
            cellsToDraw--;
        }
    }
}
```

PHP file should be good

Comment: What will I have to do to rework my code? Dont realy think that I want to have lots of forms

Comment: i will add a quick suggestion :)

Comment: Thanks for the help Luca! :)

Comment: Should I change anything in my php file?

Comment: Yes you should :)

Comment: so I added this to my php, but it did not work.     $day = $_POST['day'];
    for($i=1 ; $i < count($day) ; $i++)
    {
        INSERT INTO tabe(day)VALUES($day[$i]);
    }

Comment: Hanna, I see what you are trying to do, i was looking at your profile. I saw you had a snippet but you broke it.. you had hidden values. I will make it work as expected but i think you should start studying because your level is very very low, sorry.

Comment: Done, use the old php file :)

Comment: Thanks! :) But the php that I uploaded hasent been changed?

Comment: So I dont need to add anything to my php file?

Comment: Im asking because I tried this solution with my php and it did not work :)

Comment: I can't solve this problem Hanna.. it could be everything, sorry. If you have an error try to ask here for help, without any error i can't do nothing